# Can not install guest services ubuntu 14.04.1 for Vbox 4.3.22 r98236

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install guest services to get the screen resolution correct.
Running VirtualBox on Windows 7 with Ubuntu 14.04.1 as guest.

I get error: `unable to locate package dkms` when trying to `apt-get install dkms`

I also get the error `unable to locate package` when trying to install anything else.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

I can not find any packages!

Is there a link I can download the `.iso` image from? In Windows and use VirtualBox **virtual machine devices->insert guest additions CD image**?

Seems the Ubuntu command line can not find the packages

Comment: How did you set up networking/Internet access for your VM?

Comment: default in the settings, I was getting a toaster box saying connected to network but checked and couldn't access with web browser. Changed the VMBox network setting to bridge. Then ran apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, apt-get install dkms, and rebooted I have the correct screen resolution now.

Comment: Well then you may be able to install DKMS too. For guest additions see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Answer (score 1):

The way I have always installed the Guest Additions is via VirtualBox itself. Once booted into Ubuntu, from the VirtualBox Devices menu select Insert Guest Additions CD Image. You should find a pop up box appears telling you there is runnable software on the CD - click Run to kick off the process.

If the popup box does not appear, click on the CD icon within Unity to open the drive and then click on the Run Software button that appears at the top right of the Window.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the package is `virtualbox-guest-utils`, **not** `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`.

Therefore, the command should be -

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Comment: This will install an outdated version of the guest utilities - for recent versions of Virtual Box we should **not** install those provided by the Ubuntu repositories but guest additions matching the version of the Virtual Box installation on the host.

Comment: The version installed will be compatible with the virtualbox version in the repositories. Alternatively, the corresponding version of the guest additions iso can be downloaded from their website and installed.

Comment: Only the package provided for 15.04 are GA for 4.3.22 - for 14.04 we will only get the GA for version 4.3.10. which as said is **not recommended** to do. (Other than that, the OP said they can't install anything from the repos.)

Comment: I tried that still get unable to locate package.. my general question is i can not locate packages in the ubuntu console. Are you saying download guest services from vbox website?